# When does Clash of Clans save?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have had multiple experiences with Clash of Clans not saving (for lack of a better word) before I close the game, and not noticing until the next time I play.

For example:

I open the game and train some troops,  then close the game.  Then I come back later to check on them, but they  have disappeared,  neither in the barracks or the army camps. I assume this is because my client did not sync with the server before I closed the game.

Note: this has also occurred while over a stable WiFi connection. My Clash of Clans is connected to Facebook and Google+.

When does Clash of Clans save and how can I make sure this happens?

Comment: Are you forcing the game to quit, or just switching to another app?  I've never had this happen, personally.  Sometimes it happens when I lose my network connection, but I will often switch to CoC, tap a few things, then immediately go to another app without issues...

Comment: I have a habit of closing my app through multitasking, but lately I have been trying to close the game properly (by pressing back).

Answer (score 2):

Clash of Clans syncs almost in real time, but it doesn't tell you that you have disconnected from the game the moment you disconnect from the game. Starting at the disconnection time, Clash of Clans will attempt to reconnect. If it doesn't connect in a specific period of time, it will give you the error message. If you exit the game before re-connection, it wont save the changes. You may disconnect from Clash of Clans but still have a stable connection to your Wi-Fi or data. Before exiting the game, I always find a multiplayer match (because that requires a connection to Clash of Clans) then exit the game to ensure that my changes have been saved

Answer (score 0):

it has something to do with you not actually being connected and you just logged off.

phone connection is spotty sometimes, and what the game does is prob bunch up a few different command and then do the ingame processing on your iphone and just update some kinds of status hash back to the server.

so during that process if your connection dropped for a few second and you closed the coc it will not send your info back to the server.